Deploy Strapi alongside the Next.js client on a VPS (Hostinger)
I have a Strapi application running with a SQLite database and Cloudinary for image storage (currently in localhost). I also have a Next.js frontend running on the VPS (Hostinger-Ubuntu setup).
The challenge I'm facing is to host both my Strapi backend and my Next.js client on the same VPS.
Currently, I want to:

Host my Strapi site alongside my Next.js client site on the same VPS.
Ensure Strapi uses SQLite for the database and Cloudinary for image
uploads.

Desired Outcome:

I need to successfully run both Strapi and Next.js on the same VPS without any conflicts.

